# Trying to create multiple folders with VBScript

Tags: loops, vbscript, directory, while-loop

I need to create A set of empty folders, starting at 10, going to 180. This is the script I'm trying to use, but it just creates 10, and nothing else.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory, i
strDirectory = "\path\to\main\folder"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
i = 180
While i < 180
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory & i)
    i = i+1
    WScript.Quit
Wend
```

I'm pretty new to VBScript, so maybe the problem is obvious, but I just don't see it. I also tried using a `For` loop, but that didn't seem to work at all.

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your script as follows:

```
Option Explicit 
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory, i 
strDirectory = "C:\Temp\Test\folder" 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
i = 10  '' <===== CHANGED!
While i < 180 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory & i) 
    i = i+1 
    ''WScript.Quit '' <===== COMMENTED OUT!
Wend
```

With this script, I managed to create 180 folders.