# [in .vbs][3in1] Create multiple folder 180 => Create subfolders in All 180 => Move file and rename file in Subfolders created [3in1] "x, y, z"

Tags: vbscript, adsutil.vbs

"x, y, z" (vertical, horizontal, Move and rename files.)
i want to combine 3in1 (x,y,z.).vbs

in .vbs [summary]

Read it first here

**"x"** [Trying to create multiple folders with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824175/trying-to-create-multiple-folders-with-vbscript)

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory, i
strDirectory = "C:\New folder (2)\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
i = 0
While i < 180
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory & i)
i = i+1
WScript.Quit
Wend
```

**"y"** [Help To create Folder1/Folder2 in Windows using VBScript ( Both the folders not exists before, i mean to create multilevel folders @ a strech.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407386/help-to-create-folder1-folder2-in-windows-using-vbscript-both-the-folders-not)

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"
```

or

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs.CreateFolder("C:\New folder\Client")
fs.CreateFolder("C:\New folder\Client\subclient")
fs.CreateFolder("C:\New folder\Client\subclient\subsubclient")
```

**"z"**

```
Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
x.MoveFile "C:\myfile.txt" , "C:\New folder\myfile222.txt"
```

---

i want make

I hope you understand where I'm going with "x, y, z" (vertical, horizontal, Move and rename files.)

"x" Create multiple folders (i = 0 | i < 180 folders)

"y" subfolders (in All "x" 180 folders)

"z" and Move file and rename in new location

myFSO.MoveFile "C:\myfile1.txt" , "C:\New folder\myfile222.txt"

for 180 send to each 180 "x,y"...subfolders

---

1) Create multiple folder like script up 0-180 folders

2) Create subfolders in All 180 Folders created.

3) Move file (C:\Name.txt) and rename file in subfolder (C:\New folder\FolderB\Folder1\FolderQ\folder3\folderG\myfile222.txt)

C:\New folder\FolderB\Folder1\FolderQ\folder3\folderG

I want to combine all in one script.

---

I need [create multiple folder] [and every folder created 180] = >> [I want to create subfolders] [And move file (name.txt) and rename in subfolder]

ex: folder  i < 180 , in every folder 1-180 created I want to create subfolders, in all 180 folders

"x" Create multiple folders like (i = 0 | i < 180 folders)

"y" Subfolders like

"C:\New folder\FolderB\Folder1\FolderQ\folder3\folderG

"z" Move file and Rename file in Subfolders like

myFSO.MoveFile "C:\myfile1.txt" , "C:\New folder\myfile222.txt"

myFSO.MoveFile "C:\myfile1.txt" , "C:\New folder\FolderB\Folder1\FolderQ\folder3\folderG\myfile222.txt"

I want to combine multiple folders with subfolders in each folder 180, And move file (Name.txt) and rename file in subfolder (FolderG)

Thank you for you help.
Please excuse my English I have translated in Google Translate
I hope you understand where I'm going with "x, y, z" (vertical, horizontal, files.)

Comment: This reminds me of a `batch-file` question that was asked a couple of weeks ago.  It is possible that you all are attending the same programming class and are posting your questions on SO to get help with homework?  What is the purpose of all this -- creating hundreds of folders and moving files around...  Seems very academic (e.g., homework).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For i = 0 to 179
        SmartCreateFolder "C:\Test\MySet\Folder" & i
        .CopyFile "C:\Test\data.txt", "C:\Test\MySet\Folder" & i & "\file_" & Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 38) & ".txt", True
    Next
    .DeleteFile "C:\Test\data.txt", True
End With

Sub SmartCreateFolder(strFolder)
    ' http://www.visualbasicscript.com/tm.aspx?m=29290
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FolderExists(strFolder) then
            SmartCreateFolder(.getparentfoldername(strFolder))
            .CreateFolder(strFolder)
        End If
    End With 
End Sub
```

Thanks for `SmartCreateFolder` 2 @EBGreen